# Question about "Convention" badge (and probably applicable for others)

Tags: discussion, badges, deleted-questions

At the recent moderator election, I saw that a "Convention" badge exists and consists in "10 posts with score of 2 on meta".

First thing does "post" mean questions and answers or just questions?

Second thing I answered a question on meta that got me 6 upvotes. But I just noticed that this question has apparently been deleted and so it doesn't appear anymore in my user page answers list. Is it correct to assume that this answer won't count for the Convention badge? (if answers are considered as posts of course)

**Edit:**

So those answers have been upvoted by the community, even if the question wasn't really good.

Why wouldn't it be a good idea to still count them for a badge attribution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Post" refers to both questions and answers.

You're correct, deleted posts don't count towards badges. (However, if you get a badge and the posts that qualified you are deleted afterwards, you will keep the badge (but if it's a badge you can earn multiple times, you won't earn it the next time you qualify).)

Comment: Thanks, do you have an opinion on my edit?

Comment: @talnicolas: If the answer got upvotes, it should have been because it was a helpful or _useful_ answer (as per the title tooltip on the upvote arrow), regardless of the quality of (or opinion of other users towards) the question.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Yes I know, that's why I'm asking why wouldn't it be a good idea to still count that answer for a badge attribution?

Comment: @talnicolas Answers that no one can't see aren't useful to anyone, even if they were at one time.  I guess you could say it counts answers that **are** helping the community, rather than answers that **did** help the community.

Comment: @talnicolas: Oh, I thought you meant questions that are just heavily downvoted, but not deleted - my bad, your second inquiry isn't very clear.