# 'Your question couldn't be submitted': When submitting a Tag Wiki entry

Tags: bug, edits, tag-wiki

I just tried to create a tag wiki entry for jffs2, and got the following message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>      The tag wiki edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes!

If the same "Oops!.." text is being used for all messages, then maybe it should be changed to:

"Oops! Your *post* couldn't be submitted because"

Or something like that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure... but is the tag wiki edit queue different from the general edit queue in `/review`?  I mean... even tag wiki edit suggestions appear in that list....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a little inaccurate and should be fixed.

The term "posts" used to cover votables only (questions and answers) which is how I believe the [Convention badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112509/question-about-convention-badge-and-probably-applicable-for-others) still uses it.

Today it covers anything editable except for comments, at least in the database:

- Question
- Answer
- Wiki
- TagWikiExcerpt
- TagWiki
- ModeratorNomination
- WikiPlaceholder
- PrivilegeWiki

I am deriving this from [the database snapshot](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).  There is a general [trend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58317/tag-wiki-a-better-way-to-find-it) towards tag wikis becoming more and more like questions and answers over time, so "post" is the right word here.